# TikZ: fill a percentual part of a rectangle node

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-calc

[image]

I have a rectangle node, say 2cm times 3cm. 
Is there a *TikZ-like way* to fill a percent value, say p,  of that rectangle, similar as shown in the picture (for 34.5%). 
*So the yellow area shall be e.g. 34.5% of the rectangle area.*

I have a methode here, but this way only works, if p is lesser or equal to 50%. 
In cases, where p is bigger than 50% the filling  should be no longer a triangle as well. 
What can I do?

```
\documentclass[margin=5pt, varwidth]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[]
\pgfmathsetmacro\a{2}
\pgfmathsetmacro\b{3}

\pgfmathsetmacro\p{0.345} % percent value
% (x*a  *  y*b)/2 = p*a*b  => 
\pgfmathsetmacro\x{sqrt(2*\p)}
\pgfmathsetmacro\y{sqrt(2*\p)}

% Rectangle
\node[draw, minimum width=\a cm, minimum height=\b cm](X){XYZ};
% Fill
\draw[red, fill=yellow] (X.north west) -- ($(X.north west)!\x!(X.south west)$) 
-- ($(X.north west)!\x!(X.north east)$) --cycle;
% Annotation
\node[align=left, anchor=north west] at (X.north east){    
a = \a cm \\
b =\b cm \\
p=\p \\
x = \x \\
y = \y 
};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: If you move the vertices outside the rectangle you can clip the yellow triangle.

Comment: Mmmh, yes. But it should be the correct valued yellow area as well.

Comment: But you bring me to an idea. I could change the 'filling sides', if bigger than 50%.   The question that overlasts: is there maybe a simple TikZ-like way?

Comment: You can test if p is greater than .5. Then, change the code according.

Comment: `\if \p > 0.5  \else \fi`

Comment: Also, are you sure that `\x` should be equal to `\y`?

Comment: Yes, I will implement that tomorow. Maybe someone know a "TikZ-only way". There are some special coordinate systems, which could yield a simplier soution etc. Whaterver.

Comment: To your question: There is no need for x=y; but the equation, I have to solve is 
(x*a  *  y*b)/2 = p*a*b (see in the code too). It is easier, if I solve that for a isosceles triangle, x = y. I think.

Comment: What is input and what output? You want to compute *p* for arbitrary yellow part of the rectangle or you want to draw a yellow part with area ratio equal to a given *p*?

Comment: The ratio is p = A_yellow / A_complete

Answer (score 6):

I'd do it with clips, as Sigur suggests. This way you won't need if-then-else commands. I offer you two possibilities, the first one with the catheti proportional to the rectangle sides a and b, and the second one with an isosceles triangle (x=y).

```
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\def\a{2}
\def\b{3}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[line cap=round, line join=round]
  \foreach[count=\i]\p in {0.1,0.345,0.5,0.9}
  {%
    % proportional triangle
    \begin{scope}[shift={(\i*\a+0.5*\i,\b+0.5)}]
    \node at (0.5*\a,0.5*\b) {$p=\p$};
      \draw[clip] (0,0) rectangle (\a,\b);
      \draw[fill=yellow,fill opacity=0.5] (2*\p*\a,\b) -| (0,\b-2*\p*\b) -- cycle;
    \end{scope}
  
    % isosceles triangle 
    \begin{scope}[shift={(\i*\a+0.5*\i,0)}]
      \node at (0.5*\a,0.5*\b) {$p=\p$};
      \draw[clip] (0,0) rectangle (\a,\b);
      \draw[fill=yellow,fill opacity=0.5] (-\b,\b) |- ({-(1-\p)*\b+\p*\a},0) --++ (\b,\b) -- cycle;
    \end{scope}
  }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

[image]

```
\documentclass[margin=5pt, varwidth]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds}
\begin{document}


\begin{tikzpicture}[]
\pgfmathsetmacro\p{0.9} % percent value

\pgfmathsetmacro\a{2}
\pgfmathsetmacro\b{3}
\pgfmathsetmacro\pShow{\p*100} 
\pgfmathsetmacro\pTest{\p>0.5 ? 1 : 0}
\pgfmathsetmacro\q{\pTest==1 ? 1-\p : \p}
% (x*a  *  y*b)/2 = p*a*b  => 
\pgfmathsetmacro\x{sqrt(2*\q)}
\pgfmathsetmacro\y{\x}

\ifnum\pTest=1
\colorlet{maincolor}{yellow}
\colorlet{fillcolor}{white}
\else
\colorlet{maincolor}{white}
\colorlet{fillcolor}{yellow}
\fi

% Rectangle
\node[draw, fill=maincolor, minimum width=\a cm, minimum height=\b cm](X){};
\draw[clip] (X.south west) rectangle +(\a,\b);% else not so nice

% Fill
\ifnum\pTest=1
\coordinate[] (C) at (X.south east);
\coordinate[] (A) at ($(X.south east)!\y!(X.north east)$);
\coordinate[] (B) at  ($(X.south east)!\x!(X.south west)$);
\else
\coordinate[] (C) at (X.north west);
\coordinate[] (A) at ($(X.north west)!\y!(X.south west)$);
\coordinate[] (B) at  ($(X.north west)!\x!(X.north east)$);
\fi

\fill[fillcolor] (A) -- (B) -- (C) --cycle;
\draw[red] (A) -- (B);
\node[anchor=north west, inner sep=1pt] at (X.north west) {\pgfmathprintnumber[precision=1]{\pShow}\%};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Works for `\pgfmathsetmacro\p{0.9}` as well:

[image]