# Tikz nodes fill n%

Tags: tikz-pgf

Is there a way to fill a node for n%? E.g. 50%

```tex
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\tikzset{
  mystar/.style={
    anchor=outer point 3,
    draw,
    inner sep=.15em,
    star,
    star points=5,
    star point ratio=2.25
  }
}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[mystar, fill=yellow] {};
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You mean, filling half the node? There are some posts about that.

Comment: Related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/599474. This one is impressive: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/462473.

Comment: Thanks for the information. I did not know what question to search for.